# Entity Framework SaveChanges within extended partial of an EntityObject

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm extending the partial that was autogenerated to change the status flag of a row on the database. Right now I've got it working, but I need to call `db.SaveChanges()` from outside of the partial. Is there a way that I can get the current Entities context from within the partial in order to have it save the change immediately?

```
public partial interface IMyEntityStatusChange
{
    void ChangeStatus(MyEntityStatusCode code);
}

public partial class MyEntity : IMyEntityStatusChange
{
    public void ChangeStatus(MyEntityStatusCode code)
    {
        StatusCode = (int)code;
        //Now I want to Save it to the db
    }
}
```

Right now I have To do something like this:

```
using(var db = new EFEntities())
{
    db.MyEntities.FirstorDefault().ChangeStatus(MyEntityStatusCode.Failed);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Entity does not have to be attached to any context. What should happen then? I think `ChangeStatus` should be part of repository, not the entity itself.

Comment: In a perfect world, I'd be able to get the context, and if there was one, save it. You're probably right about it being in the repository, but saying we need to put it into the entity itself, could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would break the persistence-ignorant paradigm of Entity Framework, but that aside, there may be a possibility to do this if you insist.

First, you'd need to extend your interface:

```
internal interface IMyEntityStatusChange
{
    DbContext Context { get; set; }
    void ChangeStatus(MyEntityStatusCode code);
}
```

Then in the constructor of your context (assuming it's a `DbContext`):

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += 
                                            Context_ObjectMaterialized;
```

And the method:

```
void Context_ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
{
    var contextAwareEntity = e.Entity as IMyEntityStatusChange;
    if (contextAwareEntity != null)
    {
        contextAwareEntity.Context = this;
    }
}
```

(requires `using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;`)

The caveats are many:

- The context can be disposed any time, breaking your `ChangeStatus` method.
- This means that you need some check whether or not `ChangeStatus` succeeded. Or throw an exception when it didn't? Not nice either way.
- A disposed context will not be garbage collected as long as one of these `IMyEntityStatusChange` is still alive.
- If other properties are changed, these will be persisted as well, maybe before you actually want it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Checking if ChangeStatus succeeded isn't such a huge problem, but the context not being garbage collected makes me nervous enough to avoid this particular solution. the other properties being saved is one that I've thought of, and it seems nasty. Thanks for taking the time to show me how I would do this anyways!